# ARC converted app crashing with last call to .cxx_destruct

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

Below is the stack trace of the thread of my app which got crashed.
I have recently converted my app to ARC.
The last call is to the cxx_destruct of HomePageViewController which is rootviewcontroller of one of my tab in tabviewcontroller.
The appdelegate implemenation file is not ARC enabled for compilation so the HomePageViewController is released once its added to the tabbarviewcontroller in appdelegate file.
HomePageViewController implementation file is having ARC enabled flag for compilation.
Can someone guide me in correct direction.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35bcdf2a objc_release
1   MySample                        0x00096142 -[HomePageViewController .cxx_destruct] + 402
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35bcff3a object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35bcd0ce objc_destructInstance
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35bcd3a2 object_dispose
5   UIKit                           0x37b05c84 -[UIViewController dealloc]
6   MySample                        0x00095afa -[HomePageViewController dealloc] + 218
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35bcd484
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3801343c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop
9   UIKit                           0x37a46d94 _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler
10  CoreFoundation                  0x380a56ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
11  CoreFoundation                  0x380a39bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers
12  CoreFoundation                  0x380a3d12 __CFRunLoopRun
13  CoreFoundation                  0x38016eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
14  CoreFoundation                  0x38016d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode
15  GraphicsServices                0x35ccc2e6 GSEventRunModal
16  UIKit                           0x37a8e2fc UIApplicationMain
17  MySample                        0x0002be98 main + 116
18  MySample                        0x0000315c start +
```

Comment: Doesnt matter that your app delegate is not ARC enabled, the view controller is managed by ARC, and you manually are trying to release it.  Dont do that.

Answer (score 0):

Comment above is correct; you appear to be manually calling release on that view controller, which is disallowed with ARC. Just remove that call and you ought to be good-to-go.

Also, why did you exclude you app delegate from ARC? There shouldn't even *be* much code in that class, aside from the Core Data stack if you are using Core Data...